# Swift protocol syntax where Self: is both UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm trying to create a protocol that will automatically add a UICollectionView to any UIViewController that conforms.

Here is my current code:

```
protocol ReusableNavigation {
    var actionContainer: UIView! { get }
    func addActionMenuCollection()
}

extension ReusableNavigation where Self: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func addActionMenuCollection() {
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
        let actionMenu:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.actionContainer.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        actionMenu.dataSource = self
        actionMenu.delegate = self
        actionMenu.register(UINib(nibName: "ActionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "actionCell")
        actionMenu.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.forceRightToLeft
        self.actionContainer.addSubview(actionMenu)
    }
}
```

Obviously, the above code errors when I try to set the actionMenu delegate, as self is ONLY a UICollectionViewDataSource

I can not for the life of me figure out the syntax for the protocol extension where self would equal to BOTH UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate.

Is it possible? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add constraints comma separated

```
extension ReusableNavigation where Self: UICollectionViewDataSource,  Self: UICollectionViewDelegate { ...
```

or ampersand concatenated

```
extension ReusableNavigation where Self: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate
```